# Why are counter-based TTLs considered measurements of time?

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I'm learning about examples of TTLs (Time-to-Live fields) in low level network protocols, such as the TTL used in ICMP packets (ping/traceroute packets).

Frequently, I see ICMP TTLs referred to as measurements of time, but aren’t they just indexes/counters?

Couldn't a network of routers be programmed not to decrease the TTL in ICMP packets, therefore allowing the packet to live indefinitely?

Are they actually designed to represent units of time? Or is that just how these fields are explained?

Comment: Assumption of good faith. The reality is if on a network one device misbehavers and doesn’t respect a TTL, things will break. Simple as that. And a misbehaving device is often ignored or flagged as untrustworthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICMP doesn't have a TTL at its own layer, so your question really comes down to the IPv4 TTL.

Please note that IPv4 isn't really being worked on much anymore, as it is being slowly replaced by IPv6. IPv6 has a "hop limit" field instead of a TTL field, and the hop limit field is explicitly a hop counter, not a number of seconds.

Failing to decrement the TTL field would indeed allow packets to live in the network forever, which would kill the network since routing loops are a thing that happens more often than anyone would like. It would also break some higher-layer protocols, such as TCP's TIME_WAIT state, which work on the assumption that you can wait a few minutes to ensure that any straggling packets from a given flow that are still caught in the network will have been discarded.

The IPv4 TTL was defined in 1981 in [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) and I'm not seeing any evidence that it's been significantly redefined since. Here's what that RFC says about TTLs, on page 30:

> Time to Live
>
> The time to live is set by the sender to the maximum time the datagram is allowed to be in the internet system. If the datagram is in the internet system longer than the time to live, then the datagram must be destroyed.
>
> This field must be decreased at each point that the internet header is processed to reflect the time spent processing the datagram. Even if no local information is available on the time actually spent, the field must be decremented by 1. The time is measured in units of seconds (i.e. the value 1 means one second). Thus, the maximum time to live is 255 seconds or 4.25 minutes. Since every module that processes a datagram must decrease the TTL by at least one even if it process the datagram in less than a second, the TTL must be thought of only as an upper bound on the time a datagram may exist. The intention is to cause undeliverable datagrams to be discarded, and to bound the maximum datagram lifetime.
>
> Some higher level reliable connection protocols are based on assumptions that old duplicate datagrams will not arrive after a certain time elapses. The TTL is a way for such protocols to have an assurance that their assumption is met.

That RFC also suggests, in the fragmented datagram reassembly procedure example on page 28, that the TTL should be used as an actual seconds-based timer during reassembly of a fragmented IP datagram, telling the receiving host how long to hold on to an incomplete, partially-reassembled datagram while waiting for any remaining fragments to be received.

So, the original designers thought of it in seconds, admitted it might be more like a hop counter in many cases, but had an example where it made sense to use it as seconds. And apparently those facts aren't causing anyone problems, so no one has felt the need to obsolete RFC 791 just to remove the original notion that it was nominally seconds. But when IPv6 was developed as the successor to IPv4, the field became an explicit hop limit rather than an actual TTL in seconds.